# Where are namespaces of Aeropsike in hard drive in ubuntu 14

Tags: aerospike

I have installed Aerospike in Ubuntu. When I run aql command "show namespaces", it shows namespaces "*test*" and "*bar*". I tried to find out that where are they in hard drive or what is their exact location in ubuntu but no vain. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't see any of the namespaces directly exposed on your file system when running Aerospike.

Having said that, the "bar" and "test" namespaces are default in the configuration file and both should be configured as 'storage engine memory' which means that the data will be stored in memory and not on your hard drive. Even if you were to switch those to be 'storage engine device', and either configure the underlying device as a raw SSD one or using a file, you would still not see any direct mention of the namespace...

- When using raw SSD, Aerospike bypasses the file system and directly manages blocks on the device.
- When using a file, Aerospike also manages blocks on the file system which makes the file not 'readable'.

Comment: I meant that it cannot be directly read with a text editor to see namespace names or other metadata/data in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to see existing namespace and to create other namespaces,
If you have installed Aerospike in ubuntu then see the file /etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf . This configuration file has namespaces